# Is there a way to remove code duplication when using secrets in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have the following code in my CDK pipeline stack:

```js
        const githubSecretId = "token"
        const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, githubSecretId)

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "Example4BePipeline", {
            synth: new CodeBuildStep("Synth", {
                    input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub("username/example4-be", "main", {
                        authentication: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(githubSecretId)
                    }),
                    // other stuff
                }
            )
        })

        pipeline.node.addDependency(secret)
```

Is it possible to get the id from `secret` or somehow pass it to `CodePipelineSource.gitHub` to avoid having an extra variable `githubSecretId`? Are there any other APIs that could make this code shorter and more concise that I'm missing?

Comment: Accept the answer that solves the issue.

Comment: @gshpychka: I am aware of how Stack Overflow works, I've been here since launch day. Neither of the answers worked for me (likely for alternative reasons, not the answers themselves) and eventually I ended switching away from having a secret to get my CodePipeline working again. Thus, I don't have an answered that worked and I shouldn't accept one and yield a bad signal to whoever comes next. Lastly, your statement sounds like an order, it doesn't seat well with me.

Comment: then you are probably aware that it's bad form to leave your questions dangling - if the answers didn't work, consider adding comments to ask for further clarification. The upvoted answer should solve your issue based on the information provided.

Comment: I don't know which of the answers work. The one by @fedonev is promising, it type checks, it looks clean, but I couldn't get it to work although I believe for other reasons. In the end I ended up not using secrets by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632389/in-aws-cdk-how-should-codestarconnectionssourceaction-be-used-as-input-to-a-cod

Answer (score 1):

`secretsmanager.Secret`'s [secretValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html#secretvalue) attribute returns the`SecretValue` type directly.

```js
authentication: secret.secretValue
```