# In AWS CDK, how should CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction be used as input to a CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to have a pipeline that fetches code from Github and deploys it (Lambda, DynamoDB, etc, using CDK). I'm trying to make it work with `CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction` at the moment and my code is failing with this error:

```
  [Example4BePipeline/Example4BePipeline/Pipeline] Action Synth in stage Build: first stage may only contain Source actions
  [Example4BePipeline/Example4BePipeline/Pipeline] Action 'Synth' is using input Artifact 'Sources', which is not being produced in this pipeline
```

My code producing that error is:

```js
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib"
import {Construct} from "constructs"
import {Example4BeDeployStage} from "./example4-be-deploy-stage"
import {CodeBuildStep, CodePipeline, CodePipelineFileSet} from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines"
import {CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions";
import {Artifact} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline";

export class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        const sourceOutput = new Artifact("Sources");
        const sourceAction = new CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction({
            actionName: "Github",
            owner: "username",
            repo: "example4-be",
            output: sourceOutput,
            connectionArn: "arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-east-1:....:connection/...."
        })
        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "Example4BePipeline", {
            pipelineName: "Example4BePipeline",
            synth: new CodeBuildStep("Synth", {
                    input: CodePipelineFileSet.fromArtifact(sourceOutput),
                    installCommands: [
                        "npm install -g aws-cdk"
                    ],
                    commands: [
                        "npm ci",
                        "npm run build",
                        "npx cdk synth"
                    ]
                }
            ),
            selfMutation: false // TODO: remove before committing.
        })
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, this is the working code, much shorter/concise:

```js
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib"
import {Construct} from "constructs"
import {Example4BeDeployStage} from "./example4-be-deploy-stage"
import {CodeBuildStep, CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource} from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines"

export class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "Example4BePipeline", {
            pipelineName: "Example4BePipeline",
            synth: new CodeBuildStep("Synth", {
                    input: CodePipelineSource.connection("username/example4-be", "main", {
                        connectionArn: "arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-east-1:....:connection/....",
                    }),
                    installCommands: [
                        "npm install -g aws-cdk"
                    ],
                    commands: [
                        "npm ci",
                        "npm run build",
                        "npx cdk synth"
                    ]
                }
            ),
            selfMutation: false // TODO: remove before committing.
        })
    }
}
```